# How to map the foreign key object when reading data using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, .net-core, stored-procedures, ado.net

I want to know how to map the foreign key object when reading data using ADO.NET from a stored procedure. I am not able to map the response for `Dependent` which will be a list of objects to the response object. I have mapped the other fields into the response object. Please help me out here. I am new to ADO.NET.

These are my model classes

```
public class Employee{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   //I don't know how to map response for this property. 
   public virtual ICollection<Dependent> Dependent {get; set; }

}

public class Dependent {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int EmployeeId {get; set;} 
  public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Stored procedure

```
Create procedure spGetEmployeeAll 
as 
begin 
Select * from Employee 
inner join Dependent 
on Employee.Id = Dependent.EmployeeId
end
```

Repository class

```
    public Class EmployeeRepositroy : IEmployeeRespository{
       private readonly string _connectionString;
       public EmployeeRepository(IConfiguration configuration){
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDatabase");; 
       }
   
        public Employee GetAll(){
         Employee response = new Employee (); 
         using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployeeAll ", sql)) {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sql.Open(); 
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    response.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                    respone.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]); 
                    //How to map Dependent details into the response object? 
                }
                sql.close(); 
            }
          }
          return response;     
        }
      }
```

Comment: We don't have your table schema, what does `Dependent` refer to here? `Select * from Employee` gives us absolutely no information to work with, and any case [you shouldn't use `select *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: @Charlieface Dependent is another table that contains the name and employee id used for storing information about the dependent of the employee.  They have a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Well we have no idea how to join it. You are not actually querying it in your stored procedure so it cannot be mapped in ADO.Net, the data simply isn't there

Comment: Ok, I got it now. I have to join the tables in the query so that the result will contain the details of the Dependent table. Thanks.

Comment: Either that or return a second `select` and retrieve using `reader.NextResult()` and map it using a `Dictionary` or similar

Comment: @Charlieface Can you give a code example? I can't figure out how to store the response for  `Dependent` into the response object. The employee is having a one-to-many relationship with the Dependent. I have edited the question.

Comment: Personally, I would do it as two separate resultsets. Store each `Employee` in a `Dictionary<int, Employee>` by `Id`, then map the `Dependent` rows into them using the matching `EmployeeId`

Comment: @Charlieface Could you please give a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

It's often easier to use two separate `select` statements, and map the child rows into the parent objects:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetEmployeeAll
AS

SELECT
  Id,
  Name
FROM Employee;

SELECT
  Id,
  EmployeeId,
  Name
FROM Dependent

GO
```

You can map them in using a dictionary

```cs
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, Employee>();
    using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployeeAll", sql))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sql.Open(); 
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dict.Add((int)reader["ID"],
                    new Employee {
                        Id = (int)reader["ID"],
                        Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                    });
            }
            reader.NextResult();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dict[(int)reader["ID"]].Dependent.Add(
                    new Dependent {
                        Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                        EmployeeId = (int)reader["EmployeeId"],
                        Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                    });
            }
       }
    }
    return dict.Values;
}
```